# Nhibernate union of queries

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I am very new to Nhibernate, so this may sound silly.

I have a function which receives parameters based on what I need to make queries:

```
Public List<Data> GetResultData(SearchParams[] searchparams) {}
```

In this case, `SearchParams` is my class which has few properties say `ID` and `Name` which will be used to query.

So here are two challenges I am facing:

1. I need to make a query based *only* on the property of `SearchParams` which are filed. Say one object of `searchParams` array is like this:

   ```
   ID,  NAME 
   "34", ""
   ```

   As we can see the `NAME` doesn't have value. So my query needs to be like:

   ```
   select * from DB where ID ="34".
   ```

   The query has to be created at runtime on the basis of values available. If both properties are available, then it will be `AND` of both.
2. Since the input is an array of search parameters, there will be as many queries as the number of objects. I am trying to think of a way in which I can make a UNION of all these queries and fire them in one go.

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

A sequence of restrictions linked with or is called a disjunction. A sequence of restrictions linked with and is called a conjunction.

So, what you need is

one conjunction for your third condition
one disjunction to link the first, second, and third conditions:
So here it goes:

```
Criterion startInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedStartCanonicDate", rangeStart, rangeEnd);

Criterion endInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeStart, rangeEnd);

Criterion thirdCondition = 
    Restrictions.conjunction().add(Restrictions.le("expectedStartCanonicDate", rangeStart))
                              .add(Restrictions.ge("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeEnd));

Criterion completeCondition = 
    Restrictions.disjunction().add(startInRange)
                              .add(endInRange)
                              .add(thirdCondition);

criteria.add(completeCondition);
```